# Why is new line getting appended to my array element when I am trying to print this?

Tags: java, arrays, string, newline

```
private int Index(String[] match,String keyword){
   int m=0;
   keyword=keyword+"1";
   match[m]=match[m]+"1";
   System.out.println("match:"+match[m]);
   System.out.println("keyword:"+keyword);
   System.out.println(match[m].equals(keyword));
   while(!(match[m].equals("")) && !(match[m].equals(null))){
           System.out.println("yes");
       if(match[m].equals(keyword)){
         break;
       }
       else
           m++;
   }
   return m;
}
```

And I am getting following output (value of keyword is sparktg):

```
match:sparktg
1
keyword:sparktg1
false
```

Why in the case of match[m], there is a new line between "sparktg" & "1"?

Comment: you had `sparktg\n` inside `match[0]` before appending `1`

Comment: I just tested your code and it seems fine. Could you show us how you use it?

Comment: Also in your if `match[m].equals(null)` you will only check if array `match` on index `m` stores string "null". In case `match[m]` has no value set `(null)` you will see `java.lang.NullPointerException` because it will try to execute `null.equals(null)`. If that is not your intention use `match[m]==null` instead or in your case rather `match[m]!=null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no control over the input, you can do a `trim()` before you use the inputs. This eliminates any `\n` and spaces.

```
if(match[m] != null) {
   System.out.println("match:"+match[m].trim());
}
if(keyword != null) {
   System.out.println("keyword:"+keyword.trim());
}
```

You can make it cleaner by writing a utility method to do this.

```
public String sanitize(String input) {
    return input != null ? input.trim() : null;
}
```

and use it as so:

```
match[m] = sanitize(match[m]);
keyword = sanitize(keyword);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see is that `match[0]` already ends in a newline. You should check by outputting `match[0]` before adding the `"1"`. A good practice is to output in this form:

```
System.out.println("|"+match[0]+"|");
```

...thus using the `|` to clearly mark where your string starts and ends.

You can use `trim()` to cut off any whitespace, including newlines:

```
match[m] = match[m].trim() + "1";
```

However, this will also remove spaces and tabs, which may or may not be a problem for you. When I compare strings, I often trim both strings first, just to be safe, but only if you are disregarding whitespace.

Comment: If you're only interested in removing newlines, take a look at `String.replaceAll()` or `String.replaceFirst()`, which will allow you control over replacement via a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace all the new line before parsing.

```
private static int Index(String[] match,String keyword){
       int m=0;

       for(int k=0;k<match.length;k++){
           if(match[k]!=null)
           match[k]= match[k].replace("\n", "");

       }
       if(keyword!=null)
           keyword= keyword.replace("\n", "");

       keyword=keyword+"1";
       match[m]=match[m]+"1";
       System.out.println("match:"+match[m]);
       System.out.println("keyword:"+keyword);
       System.out.println(match[m].equals(keyword));
       while(!(match[m].equals("")) && !(match[m].equals(null))){
               System.out.println("yes");
           if(match[m].equals(keyword)){
             break;
           }
           else
               m++;
       }
       return m;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the answer, but notation about the code

`match[m].equals(null)` will throw an `NullPointerException`. The right way to check if `match[m]` not equals null is: `mathc[m] != null` before calling any method of your object. So use this:

```
match[m] != null && !match[m].equals("")
```

instead of this:

```
!match[m].equals("") && !match[m].equals(null)
```